# I'm trying to write a code in java where I'm supposed to use a function than can show even or odd digits in a specific number

Tags: java

i have 2 phone numbers

```
String telUDM   = "5143436111",
       telJean = "4501897654";
```

what im expecting my function to print

i have 7 odd digits in telUDM
i have 5 even digits in telJean

what i tried in my function is this function i took from someone's answer but i didnt work

```
final int EVEN = 0;
final int ODD = 1;

static int count(int n, int remainder)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int rem = n % 10;
        if (rem % 2 == remainder)
            count++;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Even Count: " + count(12233, EVEN));
    System.out.println("Odd Count: " + count(12233, ODD));
}
```

im expecting to write in my main :

```
function name(telUDM  , "even");
function name(telJean , "odd");
```

and to get this as result

```
i have 7 odd digits in telUDM
i have 5 even digits in telJean
```

Comment: Your last bit of code isn't Java:  ```function name(telUDM,  "even");```, so that will never work.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go with your code:

```java
public class Test {

    static final int EVEN = 0; // this fields must be static if you are calling them in static function
    static final int ODD = 1;

    static int count(long n, int remainder) { // change the parameter type to long that has bigger range
        int count = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            long rem = n % 10;
            if (rem % 2 == remainder)
                count++;
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long telUDM = 5143436111L; // cannot be integer, value is higher than max int (> ~2 100 000 000)
        long telJean = 4501897654L;
        System.out.println("Even Count: " + count(telJean, EVEN));
        System.out.println("Odd Count: " + count(telUDM, ODD));
    }
}
```

Actually it should work but phone number is too big for integer range. Here you should use string insteed (phone numbers may be much more longer). In the case when you are using string you have to iterate over all elements and parse the digit value (you can see example). But lets talk more about your code.
You cannot use non static variables in static context (static methods)
Syntax like function .... is non valid java syntax and it will not work here, you should learn something bout java basics. Anyway you cannot provide String values to methods that expect numerics like: int/long.

This should work that as you expect:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String telUDM = "5143436111";
        String telJean = "4501897654";
        System.out.println("I have " + countOdd(telUDM) + " odd digits in telUDM");
        System.out.println("I have " + countEven(telJean) + " even digits in telJean");
    }

    private static long countEven(String string) {
        return string.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).filter(Test::isEven).count();
    }

    private static long countOdd(String string) {
        return string.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).filter(Test::isOdd).count();
    }

    private static boolean isEven(int number) {
        return number % 2 == 0;
    }

    private static boolean isOdd(int number) {
        return number % 2 == 1;
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
I have 7 odd digits in telUDM
I have 5 even digits in telJean
```

Comment: The second solution is more appropriate, since the OP's input types were String, and it's a functional approach. However, I think you can dispense with the ```map(Character::getNumericValue)``` since ```digit 1 -> char 49 (odd); digit 2 -> char 50 (even)``` and so on.

Comment: Ye thats true, it would work a bit faster but It will be less readable